# Api is throwing a Cors error after pending for few seconds in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have `angular10` on `front-end` and `node.js(express)` on back-end. My all `rest` `apis` are working fine. But there is only issue with only one api.

Here is my server `app.js` code

```
// process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
const dbService = require('./services/db.service');
const { jwtAuth } = require('./middleware/jwtAuth');
const { startEmailJob } = require('./Jobs/emailJob');
const { startSmsJob } = require('./Jobs/smsJob');


const dbEnvironment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

//  connecting to database
const db = dbService(dbEnvironment, true).start();

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// console.log(__dirname + '/uploads')
app.use(jwtAuth);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
   next();
});

 app.use(cors());
 app.use(routes);


 const server = http.Server(app);

 const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3002;

 server.listen(PORT, () => {
 if (dbEnvironment !== 'production' &&
    dbEnvironment !== 'development' &&
    dbEnvironment !== 'testing'
   ) {
     console.error(`NODE_ENV is set to ${dbEnvironment}, but only production and development are valid.`);
    process.exit(1);
}
  startEmailJob()
  startSmsJob()
  console.log(`server running on port ${PORT} for ${dbEnvironment}`);
  return db;
});
```

We have our deployment `on aws-ec2` and we have our `domain(https along with redirection from http to https)` on which we are running our `front-end`.

All apis are working fine but just `file uploading` api is causing an issue. The issue i am facing is that when i call `file upload` api first time from live front-end so for the first time my `file upload` request goes for pending for around `50,60 seconds` and then it throws `CORS` like this

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pk-openmarket.openport.com:8443/api/web/upload-files' from origin 'https://pk-openmarket.openport.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

but when i `replay` that failed `request` from `Chrome Developers Console Network's` tab so it works fine and document starts uploading. So i am not getting exactly that what is the issue here?

Failed request is here

[image]

And then when i replay that failed request from `chrome` so it works fine and it's headers and specs are here

[image]

Comment: Arent you already using express cors middleware? Why are you setting headers manually? If you want to configure cors you have to pass options to it. Read more in the [manual](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors).

Comment: I was facing the same issue. The only difference in our scenario is that I am using python in lambda. Adding thiscode at the end solved my issue:   return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Success!')
    }  ... You will need to try it's node equivalent code!!

Comment: @CodeSpirit i removed those headers and still facing the issue. Basically i was trying everything i can do to resolve the issue.